# Вопрос по ResultSet

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Хочу сделать так, чтобы пользователь смог сам выбирать дату от и до которой он хочет получить данные из БД, не понимаю как это сделать, подскажите

```
protected void selectToBD() throws SQLException {
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
    ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT income FROM bookkeeping WHERE Date BETWEEN '2017-12-02' AND '2017-12-03'");
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            int i = resultSet.getInt("income");
            integers.add(i);
        }
```

Допустим если передать параметры в метод, а потом поместить значение в запрос, то не получается ничего.

```
protected void selectToBD(String str) throws SQLException {
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT income FROM bookkeeping WHERE Date BETWEEN str AND '2017-12-03'");
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                int i = resultSet.getInt("income");
                integers.add(i);
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использовал PreparedStatement, всё заработало

```
protected void selectToBD(String form, String to) {
        try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT income FROM bookkeeping WHERE Date BETWEEN ? AND ?")){
            preparedStatement.setDate(1, java.sql.Date.valueOf(form));
            preparedStatement.setDate(2, java.sql.Date.valueOf(to));
            ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                int i = resultSet.getInt("income");
                integers.add(i);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < integers.size(); i++) {
                s += integers.get(i);
            }
        }catch (SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Ну, если вы хотите подставить дату, передаваемую в аргументах метода, в запрос к БД, то не забывайте,что Ваш запрос - просто String, вот и формируйте его по правилам стринга. Конкотинацию делайте вручную, не забывая ставить кавычки, где это нужно, и все получится, примерно так:
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT income FROM bookkeeping WHERE Date BETWEEN + '"str"' + AND '2017-12-03'");

Comment: Для составления запросов с параметрами надо использовать prepared statements, а не конкатенацию строк (которая может привести к sql-инъекции).

Comment: В идеале использовать Spring Data + Hibernate/JPA и Criteria на погоны для сложных динамических запросов, тогда все вообще отлично будет, я именно так и делаю. Человек пишет имя переменной в строку и не понимает, почему это не работает. Можем помочь разобраться в проблеме на доступном уровне, а можем посоветовать то, что я сказал... Как по мне, первое полезнее